# Is this layout possible with Magento

Tags: product, layout, cart

Hi there I am looking at Magento as a platform for our CMS and have seen a layout displaying products on this site and many more.  I have seen it on mostly kitchen cabinet sites. Looks like a variable product layout of sorts.  Before I dig into magento I need to know this as my employer would like this look.
http://www.wholesalecabinets.us/cabinets/spice-shaker.html. I am interested in the grid with the image on the left and the products on the right.  If this is possible can you give me some insight on how to do it or at least if there is an extension.  I have knowledge in both wordpress/woocommerce and Joomla.

The layout should be similar to this.[image: Multiple Grouped products on the layout]

Answer (score 2):

Definitely, you can achieve this by using Grouped Product feature of Magento. Take a look at the following image [image]

You can customise the grouped product template to meet your requirements/styles etc.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that is how it would be.  I posted this same question on the "M Forum" 50 views and nothing.  You answered in very little time...thank you.  Magento is not cheap for hosting so I wanted to be sure.  I guess my only other question is there a feature to list all the grouped product in say a certain category.  Using my example there are many grouped products.. ie single door single drawer, double door double drawer etc.

Comment: No problem and of course you can list these products in any given category or multiple categories and they will show as any other products in a list on category page. Customer will go to product single page by clicking on a product to chose from the given options (related products) to make a purchase. If happy with answer please mark it as answered :) Good luck and if you needed help with dev work you can drop me an email :)

Comment: Ok thanks again.  We are just installing magento as I type.  I will add a few grouped products and see what I come up with.  Thanks for the help.  I will mark as answered after I try to get this working.

Comment: It is this particular layout we are trying to achieve.  the image on the left, the associated products on the right, heading above.  I don't know enough about php and such to do this.  I could figure it out I think but an extension i thought might help.  My problem is how are all grouped products listed with their associated products say for instance in the page in the link above.  All the products belong to the spice shaker category and as far as i can tell are grouped.